# Matplotlib Subplots: Subplot gets scaled down so axes do not match

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got two numpy arrays which I want to plot above each other.
It works, but the top image gets scaled down, so the axis do not match anymore. I can "fix" it by setting the Figsize to (8, 8), but then there is a big whitespace below the plots.

So my code:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2)

ax1.imshow(np_source, cmap='binary')
ax1.set_ylabel('Segmentiertes Bild')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))

ax2.imshow(achse, cmap='binary')
ax2.set_ylabel('Achse')
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))

ax1.grid(color='dimgrey', which="both", linewidth=1)
ax2.grid(color='dimgrey', which="both", linewidth=1)

ax1.set_anchor('NW')
ax2.set_anchor('NW')

plt.show()
```

And here's the image it produces:
[image]

How do I align them and remove the white space on the bottom too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having these issues because `imshow` defaults to fixed-aspect axes.  This adds an extra wrinkle to layout.

Your best bet is to make the vertical aspect ratio of the subplots sympathetic with your data sizes.  If you have a modern Matplotlib, you can also do `layout='compressed'` to draw the axes together vertically:

Note I made the figure grey just so you can see its extent.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randn(12, 29)
Y = np.random.randn(2, 29)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, height_ratios=[12, 2], layout='compressed', sharex=True)

axs[0].imshow(X)
axs[1].imshow(Y)
```

[image]

See https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#grids-of-fixed-aspect-ratio-axes-compressed-layout for more information.

Comment: After figuring out that the height ratio is bascially the number of the rows in the images, I got your solution to work. Thanks! Is there any way to remove the white spacing at the bottom and the top of the image?

Comment: When you save you can do bbox_inches='tight'